# Facebook share doesn't display the og image

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share

I am trying to share my blog post on fb and it doesn't display the image defined under og metatags. I tried debugging using fb debugger but even that shows the image as blank?

You could reproduce hitting below url in fb debugger
http://niyando.com/web/using-angular-js-with-rails/

I also checked and matched my image size conventions as per open graph documentation. Is there anything I missed?

Thanks

Comment: I answered a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36470111/facebook-share-image-not-showing

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question.

I am hosting jekyll based blog on github pages. For some weird reason naked custom domains do not work very well with github pages when you want to share posts on facebook. The preview just appears as blank.

I fixed this by adding www before my domain under cname file on github. I also has to reference og:image with a url prefixed with www.

Found the solution under comments on this blog.
http://ramsesoriginal.info/2015/03/21/facebook-open-graph-github-pages/